# Server high %ni (nice) load

Tags: linux

I have following problem with debian 7 (LAMP stack):

```
top - 12:16:08 up 16:36,  4 users,  load average: 27.97, 27.66, 27.42
Tasks: 240 total,   2 running, 238 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.5 us,  3.3 sy, 86.8 ni,  1.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.4 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  32980448 total, 32278828 used,   701620 free,   264368 buffers
KiB Swap: 11882492 total,        0 used, 11882492 free, 29265456 cached
```

So load average ~24 is always, even if all services (http,postfix,bind) are down (and also network is completely blocked with iptables). It near 100% nice load and ~27 la, but running processes are only 3-5. Web site works, but there is now idle at all.

Any ideas what can it be? How cat I determine which processes are running "niced"?

BTW server has 12 cores and total is is 24 threads... Is it possible that it is bug and each core is "hanging"

**UPDATE**
Process list:

```
top - 12:29:46 up 16:49,  3 users,  load average: 27.55, 27.30, 27.35
Tasks: 234 total,   4 running, 229 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.1 us,  4.2 sy, 84.5 ni,  0.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.4 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  32980448 total, 32363708 used,   616740 free,   266392 buffers
KiB Swap: 11882492 total,        0 used, 11882492 free, 29357760 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
17760 mysql     20   0 2278m 972m 8544 S    71  3.0 330:59.07 mysqld
31139 www-data  20   0 81896 4524 2076 S     4  0.0   4:27.55 nginx
31140 www-data  20   0 81776 3256 1064 R     3  0.0   4:23.99 nginx
52110 web12543  20   0  240m  14m 3328 R     3  0.0   0:00.09 apache2
33669 root      20   0  236m 7484  580 S     1  0.0   0:01.18 apache2
40600 root      20   0  236m 7484  580 S     1  0.0   0:00.76 apache2
43386 root      20   0  236m 7484  580 S     1  0.0   0:00.57 apache2
43645 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     1  0.0   0:00.54 apache2
44197 root      20   0  236m 7484  580 S     1  0.0   0:00.49 apache2
46111 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     1  0.0   0:00.38 apache2
47041 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     1  0.0   0:00.33 apache2
47644 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     1  0.0   0:00.28 apache2
48683 root      20   0     0    0    0 Z     1  0.0   0:00.23 apache2
48765 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     1  0.0   0:00.23 apache2
49749 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     1  0.0   0:00.14 apache2
49833 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     1  0.0   0:00.14 apache2
49931 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     1  0.0   0:00.13 apache2
49935 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 R     1  0.0   0:00.12 apache2
50691 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     1  0.0   0:00.09 apache2
50692 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     1  0.0   0:00.08 apache2
50786 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     1  0.0   0:00.08 apache2
50787 root      20   0  236m 7484  580 S     1  0.0   0:00.07 apache2
51487 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     1  0.0   0:00.04 apache2
51588 root      20   0 25320 1584 1080 R     1  0.0   0:00.05 top
31138 www-data  20   0 81824 3436 1064 S     0  0.0   4:18.99 nginx
45688 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     0  0.0   0:00.42 apache2
46535 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     0  0.0   0:00.35 apache2
46869 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     0  0.0   0:00.34 apache2
49933 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     0  0.0   0:00.12 apache2
49934 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     0  0.0   0:00.12 apache2
51311 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     0  0.0   0:00.03 apache2
52085 web12543  20   0  237m  11m 3272 S     0  0.0   0:00.01 apache2
62551 root      20   0 25492 1864 1192 S     0  0.0   0:07.21 top
    1 root      20   0 12708  844  704 S     0  0.0   0:04.20 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.92 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u:0
    6 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.38 migration/0
    7 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.30 watchdog/0
    8 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.20 migration/1
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.26 ksoftirqd/1
   12 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.21 watchdog/1
   13 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.19 migration/2
   14 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0
   15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.24 ksoftirqd/2
   16 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.16 watchdog/2
   17 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.14 migration/3
   18 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0
   19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.18 ksoftirqd/3
   20 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.13 watchdog/3
   21 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.14 migration/4
   23 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.22 ksoftirqd/4
   24 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.13 watchdog/4
   25 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.14 migration/5
   26 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/5:0
   27 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.25 ksoftirqd/5
   28 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.12 watchdog/5
   29 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.32 migration/6
   31 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.79 ksoftirqd/6
   32 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.15 watchdog/6
   33 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.27 migration/7
   34 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/7:0
   35 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.28 ksoftirqd/7
   36 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.15 watchdog/7
   37 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.19 migration/8
   39 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.25 ksoftirqd/8
   40 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.16 watchdog/8
   41 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.18 migration/9
   43 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.28 ksoftirqd/9
   44 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.16 watchdog/9
   45 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.19 migration/10
   46 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/10:0
   47 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.21 ksoftirqd/10
   48 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.16 watchdog/10
   49 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.16 migration/11
   50 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/11:0
   51 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.18 ksoftirqd/11
   52 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.16 watchdog/11
   53 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.44 migration/12
   54 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/12:0
   55 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.10 ksoftirqd/12
   56 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.12 watchdog/12
   57 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.35 migration/13
   59 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.08 ksoftirqd/13
   60 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.12 watchdog/13
   61 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.28 migration/14
   62 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/14:0
   63 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.10 ksoftirqd/14
   64 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.11 watchdog/14
   65 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.24 migration/15
   66 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/15:0
   67 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.05 ksoftirqd/15
   68 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.11 watchdog/15
   69 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.23 migration/16
   70 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/16:0
   71 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.07 ksoftirqd/16
   72 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.11 watchdog/16
   73 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.21 migration/17
   74 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/17:0
   75 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.11 ksoftirqd/17
   76 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.63 kworker/8:1
   79 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.42 kworker/5:1
   80 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.36 kworker/4:1
   81 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.20 kworker/3:1
   82 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.33 kworker/2:1
   83 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.12 watchdog/17
   84 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.53 migration/18
   85 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/18:0
   86 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.06 ksoftirqd/18
   87 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:06.01 kworker/1:1
   88 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.14 watchdog/18
   89 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.41 migration/19
   91 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.08 ksoftirqd/19
   92 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.17 watchdog/19
   93 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.34 migration/20
   94 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/20:0
   95 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.06 ksoftirqd/20
   96 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.14 watchdog/20
   97 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.30 migration/21
   98 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/21:0
   99 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.12 ksoftirqd/21
  100 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.14 watchdog/21
  101 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.28 migration/22
  102 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/22:0
  103 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.06 ksoftirqd/22
  104 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.14 watchdog/22
  105 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.26 migration/23
  106 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/23:0
  107 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.07 ksoftirqd/23
  108 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.14 watchdog/23
  109 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset
  110 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper
  111 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
  112 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
  113 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.14 sync_supers
  114 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 bdi-default
  115 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd
  116 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd
  117 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.06 khungtaskd
  118 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:06.12 kswapd0
  119 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.55 kswapd1
  120 root      25   5     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd
  121 root      39  19     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 khugepaged
  122 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 fsnotify_mark
  123 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 crypto
  126 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.37 kworker/15:1
  129 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.41 kworker/13:1
  145 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.76 kworker/9:1
  190 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.60 kworker/12:1
  191 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.40 kworker/17:1
  192 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.19 kworker/16:1
  193 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.84 kworker/11:1
  194 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.80 kworker/10:1
  376 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff
  377 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd
  461 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0
  463 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.02 hpsa
  467 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.97 kworker/u:1
  476 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_1
  477 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_2
  480 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.88 kworker/23:1
  481 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.76 kworker/19:1
  484 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.81 kworker/18:1
  486 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.75 kworker/20:1
  489 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.75 kworker/22:1
  497 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/19:2
  507 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.85 kworker/21:1
  508 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush
  517 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kdmflush
  524 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.36 kworker/14:2
  533 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:29.16 jbd2/dm-0-8
  534 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 ext4-dio-unwrit
  675 root      20   0 23772 1692  816 S     0  0.0   0:00.16 udevd
 1008 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/4:2
 1075 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 edac-poller
 1080 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/8:2
 1081 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/9:2
 1099 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kpsmoused
 2291 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/13:2
 2637 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:44.75 flush-254:0
 2730 root      20   0  118m 2348 1152 S     0  0.0   0:05.10 rsyslogd
 2782 daemon    20   0 18736  368  208 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 atd
 2851 root      20   0  8240  684  528 S     0  0.0   0:00.01 acpid
 2878 messageb  20   0 31864  488  220 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 dbus-daemon
 2923 root      20   0 51992 1308  688 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
 3557 root      20   0 22468 1112  832 S     0  0.0   0:00.67 cron
 3627 root      20   0 23584 1004  676 S     0  0.0   0:00.27 dovecot
 3782 dovecot   20   0 15244 1068  884 S     0  0.0   0:00.10 anvil
 3783 root      20   0 15240 1248  904 S     0  0.0   0:00.06 log
 3830 root      20   0 53648 9912 2120 S     0  0.0   0:04.89 munin-node
 4399 root      20   0 39248 2628 1860 S     0  0.0   0:00.22 ihttpd
 4450 root      20   0 54220 1568 1164 S     0  0.0   0:00.02 login
 4451 root      20   0 20384  992  816 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 4452 root      20   0 20384  988  816 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 4453 root      20   0 20384  988  816 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 4454 root      20   0 20384  992  816 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 4455 root      20   0 20384  988  816 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 getty
 5721 web12542  20   0  237m 9860 2368 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
 5724 mysql     20   0 2011m 649m  256 S     0  2.0   0:00.00 mysqld
17427 root      20   0  8304  776  628 S     0  0.0   0:00.02 mysqld_safe
23825 postfix   20   0 42008 2476 1904 S     0  0.0   0:00.01 pickup
28501 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.18 kworker/0:0
28689 root      20   0 23348 1080  552 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd
31059 root      20   0 39944 2520 1944 S     0  0.0   0:00.75 master
31073 postfix   20   0 42592 3188 2032 S     0  0.0   0:00.94 qmgr
31093 root      20   0  236m  12m 5952 S     0  0.0   0:14.22 apache2
31137 root      20   0 81476 1836  336 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 nginx
31141 www-data  20   0 81900 3512 1064 S     0  0.0   3:47.78 nginx
31878 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:05.02 kworker/0:1
32472 postfix   20   0 42008 2364 1824 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 anvil
35437 postfix   20   0 45116 3864 2508 S     0  0.0   0:00.49 tlsmgr
35880 root      20   0  206m  12m 8804 S     0  0.0   0:09.27 ispmgr
37067 postfix   20   0 46828 4368 3316 S     0  0.0   0:00.01 smtp
44298 postfix   20   0 66532 5152 3496 S     0  0.0   0:00.01 smtpd
48002 postfix   20   0 42004 2368 1828 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 error
48004 postfix   20   0 42040 2380 1840 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 bounce
48972 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     0  0.0   0:00.12 apache2
48975 root      20   0 74876 5152 2940 S     0  0.0   0:00.82 sshd
49288 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:04.01 kworker/7:1
49471 root      20   0 21636 2384 1724 S     0  0.0   0:00.31 bash
50882 web12542  20   0  242m  16m 3140 S     0  0.1   0:06.45 apache2
51111 bind      20   0  332m  55m 2352 S     0  0.2   0:04.50 named
52083 web12543  20   0  236m 9228 2004 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 apache2
52114 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:00.15 kworker/6:2
54542 root      20   0  236m 7480  576 S     0  0.0   0:00.10 apache2
55209 postfix   20   0 42020 2388 1844 S     0  0.0   0:00.02 trivial-rewrite
56098 postfix   20   0 42340 3180 2352 S     0  0.0   0:00.03 cleanup
56171 web12542  20   0  240m  14m 3300 S     0  0.0   0:00.08 apache2
56214 root      20   0 23348 1124  584 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd
56218 root      20   0 21560 2248 1648 S     0  0.0   0:00.01 bash
56282 root      20   0 73352 3732 2936 S     0  0.0   0:00.48 sshd
61268 root      20   0 21544 2280 1696 S     0  0.0   0:00.04 bash
63955 root      20   0     0    0    0 S     0  0.0   0:01.36 kworker/6:0
```

**UPDATE2**
Now after 2 days load average shows 0.00 - always!!!

```
top - 10:57:06 up 2 days, 15:17,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 377 total,  10 running, 366 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 29.1%us, 11.8%sy, 57.9%ni,  0.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.9%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32980448k total, 31662152k used,  1318296k free,   293472k buffers
Swap: 11882492k total,      744k used, 11881748k free, 25885360k cached
```

Debian bugs?!

**UPDATE3**

```
root@rd1:~# vmstat 1
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
40  0   2076 1233156 294124 25595008    0    0    26    35    0    6 94  5  1  0
29  0   2076 1240300 294124 25595200    0    0     0   428 22645 61952 86 14  0  0
28  0   2076 1233792 294124 25595456    0    0    36   364 12324 23591 92  8  0  0
34  0   2076 1251060 294124 25595608    0    0     0   556 13593 33874 91  8  1  0
39  0   2076 1223912 294124 25595752    0    0     0  2332 38084 89618 81 19  0  0
35  0   2076 1205256 294124 25595960    0    0     0   556 25791 62903 81 18  0  0
27  0   2076 1238748 294124 25596768    0    0     0   344 20367 46819 84 16  1  0
35  0   2076 1211688 294124 25597256    0    0    32   484 13068 28677 87 12  1  0
35  0   2076 1216440 294124 25597800    0    0    32   132 26783 75160 81 19  0  0
38  0   2076 1218932 294124 25598188    0    0    64  6952 19746 47230 83 16  0  0
30  0   2076 1244800 294124 25598728    0    0     0     4 16268 35489 87 13  0  0
33  0   2076 1229928 294124 25599048    0    0   184   404 10958 21926 88 11  1  0
30  0   2076 1237536 294124 25599436    0    0    32   592 12408 29603 89 11  0  0
30  1   2076 1234664 294124 25599788    0    0    12   416 13072 31855 88 12  0  0
32  0   2076 1247136 294124 25599924    0    0    12  1928 12717 23503 88 11  1  0
31  0   2076 1236484 294124 25600312    0    0    32  2880 12893 33544 88 12  0  0
```

Comment: What processes are running? You forgot to include that part.

Comment: Have a look with `top` or `ps`. Some of the kernel threads are niced. If you are using an encrypted device, the kernel thread responseble for that whould be my suspect.

Comment: Why is there apache *and* nginx running?

Comment: there is no niced procesed (except default ones) ... or I missing something? Nginx is at frontend for css,images etc. Apache - php. And there is no encypted devices... And there are no ~27 Running processes. They are mainly "S" state... Sleeping

Comment: Hmm, does `vmstat 1` show anything odd happening? I suspected I/O wait, but `top` doesn't show that.

Comment: `procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
34  0    744 1401504 293472 25886652    0    0   248   272 10934 19713 94  6  0  0
32  0    744 1417388 293472 25886944    0    0     8   272 13778 38477 91  8  1  0
32  0    744 1393532 293472 25887080    0    0     0    16 14389 36146 90  9  1  0
29  0    744 1412600 293472 25881412    0    0     0  3136 13571 25154 92  8  1  0`

Comment: The high %ni seemingly out of nowhere is one symptom of a bit-coin miner being planted on systems using an exploit of publicly accessible IPMI/iDRAC/iLO going around.